# changing xml value from java class in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to change xml value from java class.

this is my xml code and I want to set "toDegrees" value from java class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="5000" >
</rotate>
</set>
```

how can I change "toDegrees" value from java class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function

> RotateAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, int pivotXType, float pivotXValue, int pivotYType, float pivotYValue);

For example, you can implement it like this;

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f , Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, .5f);
```